# case expression for multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

OriData

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
| selected_RowNum | V6_RowNum | SeqNo | Name  | IDNo |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
|               1 |         1 | A1234 | Yummy | 1234 |
|               1 |         2 | A1234 | Yummy | 1234 |
|               1 |         3 | A1234 | Yummy | 1234 |
|               1 |         4 | A1234 | Yummy | 1234 |
|               1 |         1 | B123  | Yummy | 1234 | << I want this
|               1 |         1 | C123  | Yummy | 1234 | << I want this
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
```

Result I want

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
| selected_RowNum | V6_RowNum | SeqNo | Name  | IDNo |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
|               1 |         1 | B123  | Yummy | 1234 |
|               1 |         1 | C123  | Yummy | 1234 |
+-----------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+
```

Here is my query:

```
select 
case 
when selected_rownum=V6_RowNum and V6_RowNum=1 then 'updateonetime'
when selected_rownum=V6_RowNum and V6_RowNum>1 then 'updatemanytimes'
else '0'
end as NewColumnA, 
*
from Table #A
```

I inner join V6 and Selected table and into #A

I want to check any update between 2 tables, so I inner join both table and created rowNum for 2 tables named Selected_rowNum and v6_rownum (that sort by date). 
**Selected_RowNum = 1 and V6_rowNum = 1 (and this V6_rownum is not repeating for same SeqNo, IDNo)**

If I update 1 time, it will triggered in V6 table. If I update many times, it will triggered V6 table many time as you can see in SeqNo=A1234. As you can see, even the IDNo is repeating but it may created many applications. So, **it need filter based on IDNo and SeqNo and Selected_RowNum=1 and V6_RowNum=1.**

Any idea, how to get the result I want?

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement. (It returns a value.)

Comment: @jarlh changed my question to case expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you only want to display the results for rows where there aren't any entries with updates (V6_RowNum > 1 only?).
To do this, you'd need to check that those rows don't exist in the table, like this:

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN  selected_rownum=V6_RowNum and V6_RowNum=1 THEN 'updateonetime'
        WHEN  selected_rownum=V6_RowNum and V6_RowNum>1 THEN 'updatemanytimes'
        ELSE '0'
END as NewColumnA, 
*
FROM #A a
WHERE selected_RowNum = 1 
    AND V6_RowNum = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM #A a2
        WHERE a2.SeqNo = a.SeqNo
            AND a2.V6_RowNum > 1
    )
```

Comment: Take the time to explain your answer a little. Code only answers may not help the OP understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

If select updateonlyone time then

```
Select selected_RowNum,seqNo,IDNo
    ,'updateonetime' As OneTime
    from @tbl 
    group by selected_RowNum,seqNo,IDNO
    having count(*) = 1
```

If select updateonlyone and updatemanytimes time then

```
Select selected_RowNum,seqNo,IDNo
    ,CASE WHEN Count(*) > 1 THEN 'updatemanytimes' ELSE 'updateonetime' END
    from @tbl 
    group by selected_RowNum,seqNo,IDNO
```